# Which is new method to set value for text field

Tags: ruby, page-object-gem

I use:
`self.txtLogin_element.when_present.set(email)`

But when it executes I get a warning:

`` *** You are calling a method named set at C:/login_page.rb:12:in `specify_email'.
*** This method does not exist in page-object so it is being passed to the driver.
*** This feature will be removed in the near future. ``

How to specify a new variant with `when_present`

Variants:

`self.txtLogin_element.when_present = email
self.txtLogin.when_present.set(email)`

do not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `txtLogin_element` is a text field (`PageObject::Elements::TextField`), there is no `set` method. The Page-Object gem sets text fields via the `value=` method instead. Therefore, to remove the warning, use:

```
self.txtLogin_element.when_present.value = email
```

If you have made the switch to Page-Object v2.0 and therefore Watir v6.0, `when_present` is no longer needed. Watir now waits for elements to be present before interacting with them. You can now simply do:

```
self.txtLogin_element.value = email
```

Which ultimately means that you can just use the methods generated by the accessor:

```
self.txtLogin = email
```

Comment: ha, great, Thank you.